# Recursively add folders to export command on bashrc

Tags: bash, matlab

I want to add recursively add folders to an exported variable. Suppose I have the `MATLABPATH` variable declared below:

```
export MATLABPATH=PATH1:PATH2:…PATHN:$MATLABPATH
```

And I want to add all folders inside the folder `RECURSIVEFOLDER` to `MATLABPATH` variable. How I do that in some automatic way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` to list the directories:

```
export MATLABPATH="$(find RECURSIVEFOLDER -type d -printf %p:)$MATLABPATH"
```

The `-printf %p:` causes each directory to be printed with a `:` after it, so the find command's output will always end with a `:`. Provided `$MATLABPATH` wasn't empty before running this command, that will work fine.

Note that the above will add `RECURSIVEFOLDER` to the path, as well as its recursive children. If you didn't want that, add `-mindepth 1` to the `find` command, if your `find` command implements `-mindepth`, or replace `RECURSIVEFOLDER` with `RECURSIVEFOLDER/*`.

Comment: You may add -mindepth 1 to find command to not add the RECURSIVEFOLDER x). Thanks x)